# preview csv in html table before import in php

Tags: php, html, csv

My issue is when I click the preview button, it shows my selected file in the HTML table, but when I click import after preview it requires me to select the file again which should not be so. After preview, I should be able to import

**My html form:**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label class="font-weight-bold">Upload File:</label>
            <input type="file" name="fileUpload">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <textarea> <?php echo "$dataToSave";  ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">       
        <input type="submit" value="Preview" name="PreviewFile" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submitFile" class="btn btn-secondary">
    </div>
</form>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST["PreviewFile"]))
    { 
        $dataToSave = array();

        $csv_file = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'];

        if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )

          exit('File not found.');  


        // $sql = '';
        $row = 1;
        if (($handle = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
        {

            echo "<table border='1' style=\'width:100%; overflow:scroll\'>";
            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {

                $num = count($data);
                if ($row == 1) {
                    echo '<thead><tr>';
                }else{
                    echo '<tr>';
                }

                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                    //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
                    if(empty($data[$c])) {
                        $value = "&nbsp;";
                    }else{
                        $value = $data[$c];
                    }
                    if ($row == 1) {
                        echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
                    }else{
                        echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
                    }
                }

                if ($row == 1) {
                    echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
                }else{
                    echo '</tr>';
                }

                array_push($dataToSave, $data);
                $row++;
            }

            echo '</tbody></table>';

            fclose($handle);
        }
    } 
    elseif (isset($_POST["submitFile"]))
    {

        $csv_file = $_FILES['fileUpload']['tmp_name'];

        if ( ! is_file( $csv_file ) )

        exit('File not found.'); 


        // $sql = '';
        if (($handle = fopen( $csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE)
        {

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {


                $sql = "INSERT INTO statement ( MandateCode, BillerName, SubscriberMandateCode, AccountNumber, AccountName, PayerName, CustomersBank, Product, Amount, NoOfTrials, SessionId, DebitStatus, CreditStatus, TransactionDate, DebitStatusDescription, CreditStatusDescription) VALUES

                (
                 '$data[0]',
                 '$data[1]',
                 '$data[2]',
                 '$data[3]',
                 '$data[4]',
                 '$data[5]',
                 '$data[6]',
                 '$data[7]',
                 '$data[8]',
                 '$data[9]',
                 '$data[10]',
                 '$data[11]',
                 '$data[12]',
                 '$data[13]', 
                 '$data[14]',
                 '$data[15]') "; 

                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));

            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

        echo( "Complete!" );

    }

    ?>
</div>
```

data -

I want to be able to import after preview without selecting the file again.

I stored the uploaded file ($dataToSave) in the textarea in order to get it when the import is clicked. But the data did not display in the text area

Comment: You would need to stash the contents of the file someplace so the contents would be available should submit be selected. Or stash the file itself and add the saved name to the page so you can retrieve. Many choices but you'll need to [edit] your question and show us what you've tried so we can help.

Comment: I did that by saving it in the textarea, but the data not displaying...